# API architecture for an ontology based system

Tags: node.js, nlp, ontology, sap-conversational-ai

I am creating an ontology to store information about restaurants in a certain city. I should have an application which communicates with the user throw NLP then make queries on a triplestore.

I am not sure about what should be the ideal architecture for doing this, my first thought is:

---

User interface (Facebook Messenger or Telegram) -> NLP (Recast.Ai) -> Node.js webhook -> Triplestore server?

---

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I am going to do as an architecture for my system.

This [question](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-architecture-of-a-Semantic-Web-application) answered on Quora helped me solving the question.

In the I just should learn more about SPARQL endpoint which is going to be the port of communication to my Node.JS server. Maybe is not the best strategy but it should work for now.